# how to fix currentlyFocusedField is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Use currentlyFocusedInput

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-router-flux

I use react native, and react-native-router-flux for navigation

when I want to move screen, an error appears "currentlyFocusedField is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Use currentlyFocusedInput"

but the screen still moved with the error

how do i fix it

this is my router

```
    import 'react-native-gesture-handler';

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    Router,
    Scene,
    Stack,
} from 'react-native-router-flux';

import Loading from '../screens/Loading';
import Welcome from '../screens/Welcome';
import Register from '../screens/Auth/Register';

export default class RouterLinked extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <Stack key="root" type="replace">
                    <Scene key="Welcome" component={Welcome} initial={true} hideNavBar={true}/>
                    <Scene key="Register" component={Register} title="Register" />
                    <Scene key="Loading" component={Loading} />
                </Stack>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}
```

and this is my home page

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Button, Text } from 'react-native';

import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';

export default class Welcome extends Component {
    render() {

        return(
            <View>
                <Text>Welcome</Text>
                <Button 
                    title="Click"
                    onPress={() => Actions.push('Register')}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Upgrading your dependencies will probably fix the error.

Comment: sorry, but it's doesn't works

Comment: What version of react-native-router-flux are you using, could you show your `package.json`?

Comment: "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "0.63.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.6.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.9.0",
    "react-native-router-flux": "^4.2.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.1.1",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.9.0"
  },

Comment: its my dependencies

Comment: I also face this issue. https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/pull/8365. Looks like this issue is fixed

Answer (score 14):

I have the same issue. I fixed this issue by the following steps.

1. First find this file form the `@react-navigation` package form the `node_modules` folder.

[image]

2. Replace all `currentlyFocusedField()` with `currentlyFocusedInput()`.
3. Reload your application.

That's all.
Thanks.

Comment: So yes this fixes it, but you generally don't want to make changes within `node_modules`.  This shouldn't be committed, and any reinstall of modules will undo this change.

Comment: @mrmicrowaveoven as a workaround you can use `patch-package` to update node_modules when you install a library. https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package. Of course this is just a temp fix.

Comment: Do note this depends on your react-navigation version. In very old versions (2.x.x) you will find it in react-navigation/src/navigators/createKeyboardAwareNavigator

Answer (score 3):

This is a issue related to react-navigation package

The fix might just require find & replace all instances of `currentlyFocusedField` with `currentlyFocusedInput`

Probably this was fixed through this commit:
[Github commit](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/commit/35d6b9e3a4a28a59b3b11a67acbf7753d41705ae)
although I still get the error at my end.

Answer (score 1):

i added following plugin and fixed it.

```
  "@react-navigation/core": "^5.13.1",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.8.1",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.11.0",
```

Answer (score 0):

> We can use patch-package to update node_modules/@react-navigation/native

1. Edit "node_modules/@react-navigation/native/src/createKeyboardAwareNavigator.js":

   Find matches for this code: `TextInput.State.currentlyFocusedField();`

   And replace for this: `TextInput.State.currentlyFocusedInput ? TextInput.State.currentlyFocusedInput() : TextInput.State.currentlyFocusedField();`
2. Run `npx patch-package`
3. Run `npm i patch-package`
4. Add to your package.json scripts:

```
"scripts": {
  "postinstall": "patch-package"
 }
```

Consider discarding this patch after upgrading to react-navigation@4.4.1 https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/8457#issuecomment-698464510